# GUI wrapper for Wine 1.1.38 in OSX?

Tags: macos, mac, wine

I have successfully installed Wine (version 1.1.38) on my MacBook following [these instructions](http://davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/). Basically, I have a set of command line utilities, which I think are very nice, but I do not want to open the Terminal every time I want to launch a Windows app. Is there any application that wraps this functionality and presents it under a GUI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option might be [WineSkin](http://wineskin.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Two years later, I found this, and recommend it as still the best way to run WINE on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cedega](http://gametreelinux.com/) instead, which has a GUI, but is not free.

Answer (score 1):

[WineBottler](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/) seems to be pretty nice.